# With Has_many, how to return a list of objects without a certain related object?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My `Event` `has_many :event_people`, An `EventPerson` has, amongst others a field called "Role".

I want to find the query or WHERE to return a list of events without an `EventPerson` with role `Moderator`.

```
 Event.join(:event_people).where("event_people.role <> 'moderator' ")
```

This results in the SQL:

```
 SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` INNER JOIN `event_people` ON `event_people`.`event_id` = `events`.`id` WHERE (event_people.event_role <> 'moderator' )
```

This returns a carthesian product (it returns a single Event multiple times, once for each relation), it will still return the events even when they "have no moderator". Since events can have `event_people` with roles like 'speaker' or 'coordinator'.

What would be the SQL for this? Bonuspoints for translating that to ActiveRecord.

**Solution** in ActiveRecord, after following the hint on [having](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#having).

```
Event.select("events.*").joins(:event_people).group("event_people.id").having("sum(case when event_people.role = 'Moderator' then 1 else 0 end) = 0")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I approach this type of query using aggregation and `having`:

```
select ep.id
from event_people ep
group by ep.id
having sum(case when ep.role = 'Moderator' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

That is, count up the number of moderators on each event.  Where there are none, return the event.

I don't know how to express this in activerecord.

Comment: By pointing me at "having", and aggregates, I managed to find the correct translation to ActiveRectord. I have added that to my Question as note.